# SSH error in VS Code: Permission denied, please try again

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, virtual-machine, remote-access

I want to access a remote `VM` with `Remote-SSH` extension of the `VS Code` editor from a `Windows 10` machine. But I don't seem to succeed as `VS Code` is keeping prompting me to enter the password and deny the access each time. The `VM` runs on a `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS` `OS`.

```
stderr> Permission denied, please try again.
```

[image]

I generated an ssh key for authentication and that's how I am able to access the VM from the command line with an ssh client.

Am I doing something wrong? Is the password supposed to be something else other than the account password? Is this maybe a bug in `VS Code`?

Comment: Are you trying to log in as root? Are you able to log into the remote server (same account and password) using a normal ssh client?

Comment: @Kenster Yes I can log in normally using a `ssh client`. But I am not trying to log in as root, I created another sudeor user for the remote access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the detailed answer to this problem in the following github thread:
[SSH error in VSCode: Permission denied, please try again. #92579](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/92579)

Comment: That link didn't help at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in VS Code Source Control, and there is no prompt to enter the ssh password. I executed the `ssh-keygen -f <ssh-key> -p` command to remove the ssh password and it can be used normally.

This is a temporary solution, I hope it can help you.